# Even and odd integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the definite integral

$$\int_{-2}^{2} \Big(2f(x) + 3g(x)\Big)dx$$

where  $f(x)$ is an even function such that

$$\int_{0}^{2} f(x)dx = 3$$

and $g(x)$ is such that

$$\int_{-2}^{4} g(x)dx = -3 \ \  \text{and}\ \ \int_{2}^{4} g(x)dx = -6$$

Comment: Hint: Split the integral up (addivitivity).  Then split each of those integrals up again (property of integrals involving limits of integration).

Answer (score 1):

By the properties of the integral we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{-2}^{2} \Big(2f(x) + 3g(x)\Big)dx&=2\int_{-2}^2f(x)\,dx+3\int_{-2}^2g(x)\,dx\\
&=2\left[2\int_0^2f(x)\,dx\right]+3\int_{-2}^2g(x)\,dx\quad\text{Since }f\text{ is an even function}\\
&=2[2(3)]+3\left[\int_{-2}^4g(x)\,dx-\int_2^4g(x)\,dx\right]\\
&=2(6)+3[-3-(-6)]\\
&=12+3(3)\\
&=21
\end{align*}